# How to get notified if a state is changed by an asynchronous function in preact or react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, preact

I have an preact component that fetch a data from API asynchronously and if data is  fetched i store it in a state, then i will display that data by another function, but it seems when the state is changed it not re rendered. For example my method for fetch the data using axios is like this

```
axios.get('https://my.api.mockaroo.com/products?key=24ebcce0').then(response =>{this.setState({allProductsDummy : response.data});
      console.info('will mount all data',this.state.allProductsDummy);
    });
```

let say my function to display data is display(), i want when i call display() it will display the data when its loaded, how to do that?

Note : i separate the method for fetching and displaying because when displaying the data i need to do filter first.

Comment: Setting state should always trigger a lifecycle re-run, regardless of if it came from a synchronous function or an asynchronous one, unless you are running into race conditions.  However, `setState` is _itself_ asynchronous, so if you want to take some action only after you are certain state has been set, you should pass [a callback as the second arg](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

Comment: yes i know that, but the scenario i want is like the display will subscribe the state, when state is changed, display the data, no need to call the method to check if data is loaded

Comment: Well, you simply make sure `display()` sits inside `render()`, and `this.state.allProductsDummy` inside `display()`

Comment: Do you know that `render()` is auto called for you everytime `state` changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1**

As @Alexander correctly pointed out in his comment, the best way to 'subscribe' to the particular state change that you are talking about, is when the `axios` api call is finished and is set to state.

`this.setState()` takes a second arg which is a callback that is called right after the state is set.

```
axios.get('https://my.api.mockaroo.com/products?key=24ebcce0').then(response => {
  this.setState({
    allProductsDummy: response.data
  }, () => {
        // Do whatever you wanna do with the now loaded state
      display()
  });
});
```

**Method 2**

React has a lifecycle method called `componentDidUpdate` which takes the previous props and the previous state as arguments. You may write a function as so, that checks if the state value of `allProductsDummy` is changed or not.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevState.allProductsDummy !== this.state.allProductsDummy) {
    // If unequal, then execute
    display()
  }
}
```

Now the above would work for most primitives (string, number, boolean), however not so for objects because in javascript `{a:1, b:2} !== {a:1, b:2}` would evaluate to true, so you might need to separately take care for object equality, either by importing `_lodash` or making your own helper function.